# pyAudioAnalysis Library error: cannot reshape array of size 4400 into shape (220,10)

Tags: python, numpy, audio, pyaudioanalysis

I'm trying to extract some features of a wav file, I have this:

https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/music-emotions/ambient/13+Clock+in+the+Morning+-+Waiters+the++Free+Music+Archive+(No+Copyright+Music).wav

I'm using the feature extraction tools of the pyAudioAnalysis library:

https://github.com/tyiannak/pyAudioAnalysis/wiki/3.-Feature-Extraction

The problem is that I'm getting an error of the `reshape()` function of numpy. I'm following the guidelines of how to use the feature extractor as in the wiki like this:

```
[Fs, x] = audioBasicIO.readAudioFile('13 Clock in the Morning - Waiters the  Free Music Archive (No Copyright Music).wav')
F = audioFeatureExtraction.stFeatureExtraction(x, Fs, 0.050 * Fs, 0.025 * Fs)
```

And this is the error I get:

```
      1 [Fs, x] = audioBasicIO.readAudioFile("song-wavs/"+song.name)
----> 2 F = audioFeatureExtraction.stFeatureExtraction(x, Fs, 0.050 * Fs, 0.025 * Fs)

pyAudioAnalysis/audioFeatureExtraction.pyc in stFeatureExtraction(signal, Fs, Win, Step)
    575         curFV[0] = stZCR(x)                              # zero crossing rate
    576         curFV[1] = stEnergy(x)                           # short-term energy
--> 577         curFV[2] = stEnergyEntropy(x)                    # short-term entropy of energy
    578         [curFV[3], curFV[4]] = stSpectralCentroidAndSpread(X, Fs)    # spectral centroid and spread
    579         curFV[5] = stSpectralEntropy(X)                  # spectral entropy

pyAudioAnalysis/audioFeatureExtraction.pyc in stEnergyEntropy(frame, numOfShortBlocks)
     49             frame = frame[0:subWinLength * numOfShortBlocks]
     50     # subWindows is of size [numOfShortBlocks x L]
---> 51     subWindows = frame.reshape(subWinLength, numOfShortBlocks, order='F').copy()
     52 
     53     # Compute normalized sub-frame energies:

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 4400 into shape (220,10)
```

Can anyone tell me how can I fix the problem of the reshape and what is it that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same error, but according to https://github.com/tyiannak/pyAudioAnalysis/issues/72, I converted my stereo music to mono and it solved the problem for me.